# API Platform custom getter name for Entity attributes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have a Doctrine Entity which I want to map into an Api Platform resource:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     */
    private UuidInterface $uuid;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private string $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private DateTimeInterface $createdAt;

    public function __construct(UuidInterface $uuid, string $title, DateTimeInterface $createdAt)
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function getUuid(): string
    {
        return $this->uuid->toString();
    }

    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): string
    {
        return $this->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

It is properly shown on the corresponding resource of my api:

[image: Book resource]

What I'm trying to do now is to use a custom getter name without **get** prefix for all attributes:

```
    public function uuid(): string;
    public function title(): string;
    public function createdAt(): string;
```

But then the fields are not shown on my API platform page. How can I configure API Platform/Doctrine/Symfony or whatever so I can use custom names for my getters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing these method names, Symfony's property access won't recognize them as actual getters, and will be ingored by the serializer, it is possible to expose them using serialization groups.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"book"}}
 * )
 */
class Book
{

    /**
    * @Groups("book")
    */
    public function uuid(): string
    {
       //...
    }

}
```

However, your methods wont be treated as getters, so it may cause some weirdness with the serializer or Api platform. This is a standard convention it's best to not change them. Behind the scenes, this is handled by Symfony's [property access](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html#using-getters) component.

Comment: Actually, your solution didn't work for me: `Groups on "AdventureBook\Domain\Book\Book::uuid" cannot be added. Groups can only be added on methods beginning with "get", "is", "has" or "set".` However, this error message, along with your answer, convinced me to adhere myself to standard getter naming. Marked as accepted because of that. Thanks.

Comment: @Mochilo Usually groups works with methods, I think it is because your property and methods are using the same name?